# Why does server/client socket stop working

Tags: android, sockets, gradle, server, client

I am doing a client server app where I use an open socket on the client and server sides to establish a connection.

Client (Android phone):

```
 try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIp);
        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, PORT);
    }
```

Server:

```
        sS = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        sO = new Socket();
        sO = sS.accept();
```

The two have the same PORT value and I am sure that the server IP address is correct. It worked last month but when I tried it yesterday and it no longer  works.

If I clone it again and still didn't work (from a safe commit where it worked).

I have internet permission:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I do not know if it has something to do with gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.fran.dibcel"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'}
```

Comment: are you getting an exception when creating the socket?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: `sO = new Socket();`. Please remove that line. It serves nothing. And is confusing.

Comment: im not getting any exception i dont know what it could be the problem

Comment: 'No longer works' is not a problem description. The `new Socket()` line is not just confusing, it is a resource leak, as the `Socket` never gets closed. Don't write pointless code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was the firewall of windows. I turned it off and then i open the socket connection without any problem